# AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory implementation in Solr Suggestor not returning suggestion results

Tags: solr, solrcloud, search-suggestion

My requirement is to provide automatic suggestions to users on asset names as per their project.
I have tried using `AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory and BlendedInfixLookupFactory`, as these are the only ones that support context filtering.
But no suggestion results are being returned.
Below is extract from `solrconfig.xml`:

`<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">`

`<lst name="suggester">`

`<str name="name">mySuggester</str>`

`<str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>`

`<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>`

`<str name="field">assetname_str</str>`

`<str name="indexPath">/home/suggest_index</str>`

`<str name="contextField">projectid</str>`

`<str name="weightField">weight</str>`

`<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>`

`<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>`

`<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>`

`</lst>`

`</searchComponent>`

`<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">`

`<lst name="defaults">`

`<str name="suggest">true</str>`

`<str name="suggest.count">10</str>`

`<str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str>`

`</lst>`

`<arr name="components">`

`<str>suggest</str>`

`</arr>`

`</requestHandler>`

However if I try using `FuzzyLookupFactory` as lookup Impl, then suggestion results are returned as expected.(but problem is `Fuzzylookupfactory` does not support context filtering)

url used:
http://ipaddress:port/solr/collection_name/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&wt=json&suggest.q=Com&suggest.cfq=
1234

Answer (score 0):

(I know this is an old issue, but in case others stumble across it with the same problem...)

I spent a couple of days dealing with the same empty results.  You don't say what the type of the field is that you're using as material for suggestions.  You've got `suggestAnalyzerFieldType` set to `string`.

By default, `string` is a fieldType with no analysis many out-of-the-box schema.xml examples.  A key concept, which is only vaguely hinted at in the Solr manual's Suggester doc, is that lookupImpls like `AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory` and `BlendedInfixLookupFactory` can take a `suggestAnalyzerFieldType` that is **not** the type of the field from which you are generating suggestions, but rather *need* a type that contains the appropriate analyzer elements, such as `solr.WhiteSpaceTokenizer` needed for suggestions.

In my case, I was trying to suggest from a multivalued string field--I wanted the field to have no tokenization.  But until I changed the `suggestAnalyzerFieldType` from `string` to `text_ws` (a fieldType whose analyzer is only `sole.WhiteSpaceTokenizer`, I got empty results.

For what it's worth, if you use multivalued string field for suggestions, and many documents that contain the same string values in that field, then the `BlendedInfixLookupFactory` seems to produce a better result with no duplicate suggestions.